# Mostrar e esconder input para campo de pesquisa em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Oi estou fazendo a barra de pesquisa do site e o modelo da barra e assim: tem uma imagem de uma lupa e quando clicar na imagem, embaixo dela aparece o input para digitar a pesquisa.
Estou fazendo isso em JavaScript mas estou tendo problemas. Acontece assim quando eu clico aparece o input mais quando clico fora ele continua lá, como posso fazer ele desaparecer tentei usar if e else, for loops mais não consegui nada. Alguem poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado!

```
<script>
function mostrarPesquisa(){
  document.getElementById('pesquisa').style.display="inline-block";
 }
</scripit>

  <div id="menu">
    <div id="dentromenu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="activeItem"><a><img class="lupa" src="imagens/lupa.png" alt="Lupa" onClick="mostrarPesquisa()"></a>
                <div id="caixapesquisa">
                    <form id="formpesquisa" action="" method="get">
                        <input id="pesquisa" class="pesquisa" type="text" value="" maxlength="" placeholder="Pesquisar..."><input id="btnpesquisa" type="hidden" src="imagens/lupa.png" value=""> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: Não seria `display = "none"`?

Comment: Coloque mais informações sobre seu código, o ideal seria colocar também o html.

Comment: Sim mais quando coloco o display none, e clico fora o input continua la, o que e bem estranho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai precisar de 2 eventos:

1) **`onclick`** na imagem da lupa. Ao clicar, altere a propriedade `display` do input para ele aparecer na página (aparentemente, seu código já faz isso)

2) **`onblur`** no input de pesquisa. O evento `onblur` é executado quando o elemento perde o foco. Dessa forma, quando o input perder o foco, mude a propriedade `display` para `none`

**Altere no seu HTML:**

```
<input id="pesquisa" class="pesquisa" type="text" value="" maxlength="" placeholder="Pesquisar..." onblur="esconderCampoPesquisa()">
```

**e adicione essa função:**

```
function esconderCampoPesquisa() {
   this.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Obs:** Seu elemento input deve estar inicialmente escondido. Adicione uma classe CSS para ele, setando o `display` para `none`

Comment: Cara muito obrigado funcionou!

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar um EventListener:

```
document.getElementById("pesquisa").addEventListener("blur", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("pesquisa").style.display = "none";
}
```