# Pegar os dados de um select e declarar variável

Tags: php, codeigniter, input, html-select, declaração-de-variável

tudo bem?
Sou bem novato em programação e tenho uma dúvida simples q não encontrei aqui no fórum.
Tenho esse código abaixo da view (feita em codeigniter):

```
<div class="span6">
      <label for="formaPgto">Forma Pgto</label>

      <select name="formaPgto" id="formaPgto" class="span12">
        <option value="Dinheiro">Dinheiro</option>
        <option value="Cartão de Crédito">Cartão de Crédito</option>
        <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
        <option value="Boleto">Boleto</option>
        <option value="Depósito">Depósito</option>
        <option value="Débito">Débito</option>        
      </select> 

  </div>
```

Eu quero que quando a pessoa escolha a opção Cheque, abra um campo abaixo, com uma input type text, para inserir o numero do cheque (OBS: já criei a coluna numCheque e numCartao no BD). E o mesmo, quando o usuário escolha Cartão de Crédito.

Não consegui resolver isso. Se alguém puder me ajudar, fico muuuito grato.

Comment: Você podia resolver isso com javascript. Veja essa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93779/mostrar-e-esconder-input-para-campo-de-pesquisa-em-javascript Espero ter ajudado, MDC

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo... Más com o JS daria pra gravar no BD? Ou só com o php mesmo?

Comment: Vc cria o input normalmente tal como criou os outros e a unica coisa q o javascript faz é escondê-lo ou mostrá-lo no onclick da opção cheque, com php voce pega normal pelo name, e tal e qual como se ele fosse sempre visivel

Comment: Se quiser salvar no BD, usa $ajax para salvar no banco via PHP. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Pessoal... estou tentando fazer os campos iniciarem escondidos más não tá dando. Assim q abre o "modal" de faturar, já aparece os campos. Já fui no CSS e coloquei como display: none, e mesmo assim continua aparecendo. Fui no JS e criei uma funçao pra esconder os campos com o this.style.display="none" e ainda está lá. Quanto ao fato de gravar no BD, faço pelo controle e a principio esta dando certo.

Answer (score 1):

Vou refazer a resposta com todo o código para este caso:

```
<div class="span6">
      <label for="formaPgto">Forma Pgto</label>

<select name="formaPgto" id="formaPgto" class="span12" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
        <option value="Dinheiro">Dinheiro</option>
        <option value="Cartão de Crédito">Cartão de Crédito</option>
        <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
        <option value="Boleto">Boleto</option>
        <option value="Depósito">Depósito</option>
        <option value="Débito">Débito</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="numCheque" id="numCheque" style="display: none">
  </div>

<script>
function yesnoCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "Cheque") {
        document.getElementById("numCheque").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("numCheque").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Peço desculpa se alguma confusão, MDC.

PS:Testei o código e funciona perfeitamente, basta vc pegar e colar num ficheiro com extensao .html.

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321494/show-input-field-only-if-a-specific-option-is-selected

Comment: Muito Obrigado MDC. Vou testar aqui e qualquer coisa eu posto. Deus sempre os abençoe em tudo!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente amigo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @JardelDint se precisar de mais alguma ajuda disponha. Sorte para seus projetos, MDC (ou Moca De Cebola :)

Comment: Amigo... sem querer te incomodar mais uma vez... tentei fazer o mesmo pra Cartão de Crédito. Más colocando o mesmo código, apenas mudando de Cheque pra Cartão de Crédito (com espaços e acento), o mesmo não acontece. O if aceita string com espaços e tals?

Comment: Achei meu erro..... kkkk... tinha me esquecido de fazer a input do cartao de crédito... kkkk.. Desculpa e mais uma vez obrigado!